# Julia Command Line Operators Append

Tags: bash, julia

I'm trying to chain/pipe some commands (say cat, grep,) together and append the results to a file...what would the append operator in Julia be in that setting ala

```
 run(`cat $gx` |> `grep $datef` ###APPEND OPERATOR### $newfile)
```

Comment: The operator in question is  `>>`. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/?highlight=run#Base.>>

Comment: Funny I thought I tried that. Will give it a whirl. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
julia>run(pipeline(`cat $gx` & `grep  $datef`) >> $newfile)
```

Credits to @jubobs for giving the answer in the comments, just that `|>` is deprecated, use `pipeline` instead.